# select a row in datagridview programmatically

Tags: c#

I had a data grid with more than 100 rows on it 
if the user click the first column of the row the whole row must be selected and if he click on any other column it must not select the whole row 
I set the selection mode of datagridview  cellselection and  made it read only also and  tried all the below code but found no use can any one suggest any idea

```
private void tbljobdata_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (tbljobdata.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        tbljobdata.Rows[tbljobdata.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle mouse down event since thats captured the first.

```
private void tbljobdata_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        tbljobdata.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    else
        tbljobdata.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
}
```

Alter the read only property too accordingly under the condition required.. you can set readonly for individual cells in fact if you want

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
private void tbljobdata_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        tbljobdata.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

For further reading on `CellClick` event here is [Docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick).